# jQuery IU Autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I using jQuery-UI Autocomplete. When user types some text autocomplete send async request. But user not waiting response and moves to other input. How i can cancel request?

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel an ajax request.  Take a look at this:

[Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery)

You should be able to bind a focusout event to your input that will kill the ajax request.

Comment: Yes, I can, but input with autocomplete still waiting data (loading icon on the right not hiding)

Comment: Thanks fehays! I just change css of this input.